# Program to add "Cycle through programs in group" as a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

One shortcut I missed when switching from Mac OS X back to XP was the ability to cycle the windows of an single app using Command+`.

When I upgraded to Windows 7, I was excited to see that it has this feature, kind of: You can ctrl+click on a grouped taskbar icon to cycle through the group. It works, but I hate having to use the mouse to do it. Before I go installing every shortcut mapper known to man, is there one that you know has the ability to map a key to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vistaswitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html) kind of does this. With Vistaswitcher:

> you can cycle through your open documents as easily as you do with your open applications, using Alt + ` (grave accent or backtick) – just like on Mac OS.

Win +F11 also does the job. The key combos are not configurable within Vistaswitcher, but maybe in conjunction with Autohotkey you can make it behave just as you want.

Loads of other great features too.

Comment: Nice! Small, simple program, and you can turn off the main alt-key replacement if you want (although that also removes the Alt + ` shortcut). Exactly what I was looking for.